logarithmic inequality $\log_x64 < 2$
I tried to solve this inequation and I got the solution.
So $\log_x2^6=6\log_x2$, then i divided by 6 both sides and I got $\log_x2<\frac{1}{3}$.
I multiplied by 3 and put it into logarithm and got $\log_x8<1$. We know that $\log_xx=1$, so finally I got equation $8<x$. In my answers this is only a part of the answer. The answer also contains other set. I tried to look for properties but couldn't find anything.
What am I missing?

$$\log_x64=\frac{\ln64}{\ln x}$$
and the missing solution set is $0<x<1$, since $\log_x64$ is then negative.

If $x>1$:
$\log_x64 < 2$ then $x^{\log_x64} < x^{2}$, therefore $64<x^{2}$.
The set of solutions when $x>1$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 8<x \}$.
(We don't take negative values for x because it is positive since it is base for logarithm)
But as in answer of Parcly Taxel: we should include the values  between zero and one, so the set of solutions is:
$\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 8<x \hspace{.1cm} or \hspace{.2cm} 0<x<1\}$
