logarithmic inequation $log_x4>-2$
I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here, but here are the steps I'm taking.
I figured that for this inequality the answer would be in 2 sets from (0,1) and (1,+inf). First I take $log_x2^2$ and put it in front $2log_x2$. then I divide by 2 and I get $log_x2>-1$. Now I substitute $log_x2>log_xx^{-1}$ and finally I get $2>x^{-1}$. From here it's easy to multiply by $x$ and divide by 2 and get the final answer $x>\frac{1}{2}$. But the issue is one of the answers is the set $(0,\frac{1}{2})$. What am I doing wrong?

Think again about the step from $\log_x2>\log_x x^{-1}$ to $2 > x^{-1}$.

I would also suggest to read the answers to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4923733/42969 again.

I checked my previous thread before asking that question, Thanks.

In that step you mentioned the inequality changes to < because we are multiplying by negative x?

It changes if $\ln x$ is negative, i.e. if $0 < x < 1$.
